# Rollup plugin scss doesn't embed/import css in final index.js

Tags: css, sass, react-component, rollupjs

I' ve got this simple library:

```
src
L component
  L Player.tsx
    PlayerUI.style.scss
  index.ts
```

Player.tsx import the scss:

```
import './PlayerUI.style.scss';
```

with this roll-up config:

```
const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      // {
      //   file: packageJson.main,
      //   format: "cjs",
      //   sourcemap: true,
      // },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      del({ targets: 'dist/*' }),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      json(),
      scss(),
      livereload(),
    ],
    external: ['react-dom', 'axios', 'react-redux', 'react', '@reduxjs/toolkit', 'react-audio-player'],
  },
  {
    input: 'src/components/player-ui/PlayerUI.style.scss',
    output: [
      { file: "dist/esm/components/player-ui/PlayerUI.style.scss" }
    ],
    plugins: [
      scss()
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    plugins: [dts(),]
  },
];
```

I get this:

```
dist
L esm
  L components
    Player.d.ts
    PlayerUI.style.scss
  **index.css**
  **index.js**
  index.d.ts
```

The library itself works pretty well, but I get no css style in browser.

I checked the index.js file, and there is no import instructions, or stringified css in it. **Basically, the index.css file is isolated, no one calls/imports it.**

What am I missing?

Comment: I have the exact same issue and have not found a solution. *following